How to change page icon color in browser tab
Fontawesome free icons are used as page icons like
<html><head>
<link rel='icon' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/svgs/solid/pen-to-square.svg'>
</head></html>

Black icon appears is Chrome tab:

How to change this icon color?
Bootstrap 5 is also used.
Inside html page color can changed using bootstrap text-danger class like
<i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square text-danger"></i>

or using style:
.fa-pen-to-square {
    color: red;
}

How to change page icon color also ?
This is ASP.NET 9 MVC application using FontAwesome free SVG icons, Bootstrap 5, jquery and jquery ui.
Update
It looks like color attribute like
fill = "#AB7C94"

should be injected to SVG as described in How can I change the color of an 'svg' element?
and inline data uris should used for page icons.
Colors are specified as html color names. How to use html color names in svg or covert them to color hex values required in svg?
Or can svg filter applied to FontAwesome icons? No sure will FontAwesome free icon license allow icon modifications.

Unfortunately, the favicon color cannot be dynamically changed using CSS classes or styles applied in the HTML because the browser renders the favicon as a standalone image resource, separate from the DOM. To change the color of a FontAwesome icon used as a favicon, you need to modify the SVG file itself.

SVG file is loaded from CDN. Where to find CDN which allows to download colored free site icons or allows to specify color? Or how to create controller in C# which pre-processes SVG from CDN url to change color? Or is there some online color changer application? I can change SVG color using this and serve colored SVG from my site instead on CDN

Most CDNs, including FontAwesome, serve their SVGs in a default black color or without color. They don’t provide dynamic color customization. However, you can:
Search for services that allow color customization in SVGs dynamically (though these are rare and usually not free).
Tools like SVGOMG or similar SVG editors let you upload and edit SVG files.

Where to find C# code which reads SVG and changes its color? This code and used to pre-process FontAwesome SVGs from CDN.

@Saikat... You gave the right answer. I think you should rewrite your comments as an answer and get credits for it.

Saikat wrote that SVG should modified.  It does not contain C# code which modifies SVG file to change its color. Answer should contain C# code which changes SVG file color.

Why should it be modified by code? Do you need this for more than the one icon you have shown us; do they need to be switched / selected dynamically? If you need this only for this single one - then I would recommend you place a copy in your own system, and simply modify that file, once.

There are about 50 icons whose colors should modified. Desired colors and icons may change. I'm looking for automatic solution, not editing every icon manually every time. Problably simple string processing can used to add color to SVG. Colors are specified by html color names like olivedrab, deeppink. How to convert them into colors which can be put to SVG? Can SVG filter applied so that original SVG is not changed, not sure will FontAwesome free icon license allow icon modifications. Using inline url images decreases number of requests does not require saving copies.

I updated question and added svg modification in Updated part.

A data URL is just a string. Construct it with whatever colour you want. You can use HTML colour names in SVG just fine. Various answers in the linked question show how to do it so what exactly is the problem with using one of those answers?

Those answers do not contain C# code. I'm looking for a C# sample code or nuget package which reads svg from Fontawesome or other free library distribution in wwwroot or from CDN, adds color and returns data URL as string.

Too broad then.

I posted linked question but it was marked as duplicate.

At no point have you explained what the problem is in detail. a) you don't know how to parse XML in c# if a) is not the problem then show your parsing code. b) you can parse XML but you can't find an element in the DOM. c) you can find an element in the DOM but you can't set it to a new value. Which is it?

It looks like svg icons are stored in wwwroot\lib\font-awesome\sprites\  folder in three different svg files. Looking for a code to find svg from icon class name from those files and inject color into this svg.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Unfortunately, the favicon color cannot be dynamically changed using CSS classes or styles applied in the HTML because the browser renders the favicon as a standalone image resource, separate from the DOM. To change the color of a FontAwesome icon used as a favicon, you need to modify the SVG file itself.
Most CDNs, including FontAwesome, serve their SVGs in a default black color or without color. They don’t provide dynamic color customization. However, you can: Search for services that allow color customization in SVGs dynamically (though these are rare and usually not free). Tools like SVGOMG or similar SVG editors let you upload and edit SVG files.

svg for icons is stored in wwwroot\lib\font-awesome\sprites folder in three xml files. Where to find c# code a code to extract svg from icon class name from those files and inject color into this svg by html color name? Is there xml parser which reads those files sequentially and stops after svg is found?
